# Use a Joystick in qnode.cpp

Tags: c++, catkin, qt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

i am quite new to ROS and c++, so excuse if if this question is an easy one, plz :)

i created a package with catkin_create_qt_package and now i want to use a JoyListener.

The problem is, that i really don't know how to integrate the code? I found some examples for using the joy.h node, but nothing for using it in the catkin created qt package :( Do i have to add the code in qnode.cpp ?

Sorry for my english XD i don't know how to explain my problem :3

[Edit]
Sorry, i don't get it :(
I used this code for subscribing the joy-node:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::Joy>("joy", 10, &QNode::joyCallback);
```

And this is my prototype of the joyCallback-function:

```
void QNode::joyCallback(const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& joy_msg)
{
 ros::Publisher chatter_publisher.publish(joy_msg); 
}
```

but i get this strange error and don't know what it means...

```
/usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:225: error: no match for call to ‘(boost::_mfi::mf1<void, test_joy::QNode, const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> > >&>) (const boost::shared_ptr<const sensor_msgs::Joy_<std::allocator<void> > >&)’
```

do you have any idea of what i'm doing wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110106/use-a-joystick-in-qnode.cpp/) by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-12-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-13**:
Do you want to receive joystick messages? In that case check out the standard subscriber tutorial.

**Comment by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on 2013-12-13**:
i want to use the joystick for controlling an AR Drone. I thought it would be fine to display the pressed buttons in an QT gui, but i dont know how to check, which button is pressed from the gui package :/

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-12-13**:
If you want to know which buttons are pressed on a running joystick node then subscribe to a sensor_msgs/Joy message. It's usually on the /joy topic.

**Comment by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on 2013-12-13**:
Ok thanks, i'll try it out :)

**Comment by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on 2013-12-13**:
I don't get it >___< i updated the question to what i have done to subscribe the joy-messages.. help plz :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The compiler is complaining because the pointer to a JoyStick message passed to your callback is not a valid parameter to the `chatter_publisher.publish()` method.

What in the world was that statement supposed to do?

```
ros::Publisher chatter_publisher.publish(joy_msg);
```

*This is not a forum for basic C++ language questions.*

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on 2013-12-14**:
sorry to ask stupid questions, i am new to c++... but i found out that this is not the real problem at all... i deletet this line and replaced it...but it seems as if my subscriber is not even entering my joyCallback(...)... whatever.... :(

**Comment by [Cookie](https://answers.ros.org/users/9861/cookie/) on 2013-12-14**:
Aaargh ok i found the mistake, it was the joystick itself..... thanks for helping me! :D